# XSLT for removing duplicate node based on node attribute

Tags: xslt

I need to remove complete parent node based on selection on other element value.

My XML is

```
<EAI>
    <SvcRS>
        <accountHeader>
            <errorHost>orgA</errorHost>
        </accountHeader>
        <accoutnDetails>
            <accountNumber>0000000111118800</accountNumber>
            <accountType>credit</accountType>
            <errorDetails>
                <code>111</code>
                <description>Account is not valid</description>
            </errorDetails>
        </accoutnDetails>
    </SvcRS>
    <SvcRS>
        <accountHeader>
            <errorHost>orgB</errorHost>
        </accountHeader>
        <accoutnDetails>
            <accountNumber>000111118800</accountNumber>
            <accountType>credit</accountType>
            <errorDetails>
                <code>0001</code>
                <description>Not enough balance</description>
            </errorDetails>
        </accoutnDetails>
    </SvcRS>
</EAI>
```

Now, i have to check `<errorHost>` if it is `orgA` then on same account number `111118800`, i have to remove `<accountDetails>` of `orgB`, In XML there can be multiple accounts, so for all i have to remove all details of `orgB`

I am trying many option but nothing is working it seems.

Output

```
<EAI>
    <accoutnDetails>
        <accountNumber>111118800</accountNumber>
        <accountType>credit</accountType>
        <errorHost>orgA</errorHost>
        <errorDetails>
            <code>111</code>
            <description>Account is not valid</description>
        </errorDetails>
    </accoutnDetails>
</EAI>
```

Comment: _I am trying many option but nothing is working_ - Please share whatever you have tried and the desired XML output.

Comment: Hi Aniket, As i said, I have product which have option to work on, but built in tool is not capable enough to perform complex manipulations,
i have updated desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="accoutnDetails[errorHost = 'orgB' and //accountNumber = accoutnDetails[errorHost = 'orgA']/accountNumber]"/>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

See transformation at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/b4GWV8

for your updated query try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SvcRS[accountHeader/errorHost = 'orgB' and accoutnDetails/accountNumber = //SvcRS[accountHeader/errorHost = 'orgA']/accoutnDetails/accountNumber]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See transformation at http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEmq

Comment: Hi Aniket,
 this is working like a charm, Can i ask you one more thing, if errorHost is not under accoutDetails instead it is under accountHeader

Comment: @kekukeku, for these you have to edit xslt and add extra condition for accountHeader.

Comment: In updated case you want to remove `SvcRS` or only accoutnDetails

Comment: I have to remove complete node SvcRs

Comment: Thanks Aniket and Rupesh, Working as expected!!

Comment: Can i ask you guys one more query, If i have 0000 leading zeros in account number, can i remove using xslt?

Comment: see updated transformation [http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEmq/1](http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEmq/1)